# Group results of different types in response structure

Tags: elasticsearch, types, grouping, response

I need to build a searchable index of some data to be presented in a client, with each type having its own section in the results list and only showing the top 5 items. Let's say we have publications with 3 different types of media: DVD, CD and LP (Vinyl). All have properties like artist, title, length, number of tracks, genre etc.

Let's say I indexed the content with 3 types, called dvd, cd and lp.

When I do a search like http://localhost:9200/myindex/_search?q=name:Metall*

I want to have a response with the 5 items for each group, a total number of matches in the group, and maybe af human readable name of the group. Probably looking like this:

```
{  
   "groups":{  
      "dvd":{  
         "name":"DVD",
         "results":65,
         "content":[  
            {  
               "id":1,
               "title":"blablabla"
            },
            {  
               "id":4,
               "title":"nananana"
            },
            {  
               "id":5,
               "title":"foo bar"
            }
         ]
      },
      "cd":{  
         "name":"CD",
         "results":31,
         "content":[  
            {  
               "id":43,
               "title":"lalala"
            }
         ]
      },
      "lp":{  
         "name":"Vinyl",
         "results":5,
         "content":[  
            {  
               "id":543,
               "title":"buaaah"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Is it possibly in any way, tweak elasticsearch to output a result like this?

Or should I make the grouping in the mobile client, make 3 separate requests, or have a service in front of elasticSearch which makes the separate requests and combine them into the structure I suggest here?

Comment: Why don't you execute 3 separate queries to get the results? Would that not solve your problem?

Comment: That could be a way to solve it. But the client is a mobile App and the groups of results that we want to display could be changed on demand. Therefore, it would be great if elastic search could just return the results grouped and with "human readable" names for each group.

Then we would't have to make some extra configration management for the search results view.